Moving to elastic cache serverless
Currently we are using AWS elastic cache in one of our production account. We are thinking to moving to elastic cache serverless, believing it will reduce a part of our bill. While using aws calculator for determine the cost for elastic cache serverless we need some data from our current work load in the production account. 1.Average cache data size (in GB) 2.Average simple request rate 3.Average data transferred per request [KBs]
From the production account i have only the metric data related to AWS elastic cache, How can i get or calculate the above 3 data for the current workload i have in my production account. So that i can calculate the cost for AWS elastic cache serverless and ensure it will save cost or not

AWS CloudWatch provides metrics you're looking for.
Here is some mertics you might be interested in:

The DatabaseMemoryUsagePercentage can be used for memry consumption, you need to multiply it to the total memory allocated by your nodes.
Both CurrConnections and NewConnections will give you a request rate.
If you divide BytesReadIntoMemcached and BytesWrittenOutFromMemcached by the number of requests you will get the average data per request.

